# How to set up SPI Communication between STM32F401REtx and MCP2515

Tags: stm32, spi

master-STM32F401REtx (stm32 nucleo)
slave - MCP2515

i connected mcp2515 with           **
1.crystal oscillator (20Mhz + two 15pf external capacitors)
2.power supply(3.3 v0lts) with a bypass capacitor(33pf).
3.reset pin pulled up with 10Kohm to vdd(3.3V)
4.MISO,SIMO,CS,SCK(1Mhz)**

i am able to read and write the registers, when i try to change the mode of mcp2515 with CANCTRL register ,the CANSTAT register should be updated with that mode but  CANSTAT register is read as default value(0x80).
please guid me how to make it to change the mode.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104231/discussion-on-question-by-sunil-kumar-reddy-how-to-set-up-spi-communication-betw). Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

**i have changed crystal with 4 MHz**.now mcp2515 is working fine.if i try to change its modes, it is changing to configure  modes  and normal mode only but not to any other modes.
very rarely, mode is changing to desired but not consistently. ** there is no issue with mode changing to configure  modes  and normal mode**.